# Como abrir Certificate Store e selecionar certificado com Java?

Tags: java, certificado-digital

Gostaria de saber como é possível abrir a certificate store do Windows e selecionar o certificado a ser usado utilizando a linguagem Java.

Utilizando a CAPICOM e até mesmo as classes X509 do C# o resultado obtido é este:
[image: Certificate Store do Windows]

Porém não consigo reproduzir o mesmo resultado utilizando Java.

Alguém tem ideias, sugestões ou solução?